# HTML/CSS/JS: Simple div not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just want to understand why the `#div` element is not appearing anyway at the simple following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

  <div id="div"></div>


   <style>
  #div{
  color:black;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  }
  </style>
    <script>
   function algo(){
    alert("ALGO");
   }

  document.querySelector("#div").onclick = algo;
 </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/26pkt2y6/

Comment: do you think `color:black` should paint the whole rectangle black?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/26pkt2y6/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`color` would mean the foreground color. Since there's no text to show, it appears that the div isn't displaying. Set the `background` to see the div.

```js
function algo() {
  alert("ALGO");
}

document.querySelector("#div").onclick = algo;
```

```css
#div {
  color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Because it's empty, try to add some content between the div tags, or if you want to have a block like a button you have to change the CSS to:**

```css
<style>
  #div{
  background-color:black;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  }
  </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  div{
  color:black; change this to background-color:black;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use background-color for the color

Answer (score 0):

Your div is empty, set a text or styling with css, you should used background-color instead of color:

```js
function algo(){
    alert("ALGO");
}
document.querySelector("#div").onclick = algo;
```

```css
 #div{
  background-color:black;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```